# How to achieve database independency when using jdbc

Tags: java

I want that when I am using jdbc and java to connect to a database it should connect to multiple database

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad, but to answer your question to a certain extent, you can do that with multiple JDBC connections to different databases. Each of the database would require a specific connection string and database specific JDBC driver...

Hence, for you to connect to multiple databases using JDBC & Java - you would be able to do that loading the vendor specific drivers and create a connection per database that you would want to connect.